# How can I show a "div" that pops up from within a "div class='slds-scrollable_x'" over all other elements?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforcedx, css, slds

*THE CONTEXT:*

I am in the process of implementing via HTML and SLDS styling, a **datatable** that is **inline editable** and has resizable columns.
When the user clicks on a cell, an **input 'pop up'** is shown to edit the same cell's data, just like in the following picture:
[image]

Notice (as I have commented in the picture) that the pop up is fully showing; this is only because I have added to my table's style some bottom-margin (style='bottom-margin:10vh, to be precise) just so I can show you how this mechanism is supposed to appear. **If I hadn't added the bottom-margin, then the 'pop-up' wouldn't show.**

The problem becomes more apparent when trying to edit a 'Roles' cell which pops-up a dual list box:
[image]
**As you see the dual list box isn't fully showing**. The pop-up mechanism is implemented through CSS's **z:index** property, you'll also get to see it in my code.

*THE QUESTION:*

How can all my 'edit pop-ups' fully show above everything? I want them to show even over my 'Legal Representatives' table which is right underneath the table I have been editing in the previous pictures. I presume that the pop ups aren't fully showing due to my outer 'div class='slds-scrollable_x' slds class.

*MY CODE:*

some notes:

1. The thead for my table is implemented within my component 'el_ContactsDataTable'.
2. The tbody for my table is implemented within my component 'el_ContactsDTInlineRowEdit'

el_ContactsDataTable.cmp:

```
<aura:component>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>

<!--declare aura attributes-->
<aura:attribute name='isIndividualAccount' type='Boolean' default='false' />
<aura:attribute name='ACRs' type='AccountContactRelation[]' />
<aura:attribute name='roleOptions' type='Object[]' />

<!-- attributes needed for column resizing-->
<aura:attribute name='tdWidth' type='Double' />
<aura:attribute name="mouseStart" type="string" />
<aura:attribute name="newWidth" type="string" />
<aura:attribute name="currentEle" type="Object" />



<div class="container" onmouseup="{!c.resetColumn}">
    <div aura:id='theTable' class="slds-table--header-fixed_container slds-scrollable_x">
        <div class="">
            <table  class="slds-table slds-table--header-fixed slds-table_bordered slds-table_edit slds-table_resizable-cols" style="table-layout:fixed;margin-bottom:10vh">
                <thead>
                    <!-- thead code removed because its irrelevant -->
                        
                </thead>
                <tbody onmousemove="{!c.resetColumn}">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.ACRs}" var="acrIter" indexVar="sNo">

                    <c:el_ContactsDTInlineRowEdit aura:id='{!acrIter.Contact.Id}' contact="{!acrIter.Contact}"
                        accountContactRelation="{!acrIter}" isIndividualAccount="{!v.isIndividualAccount}"
                        sNo="{!sNo + 1}" roleOptions='{!v.roleOptions}' />
                    </aura:iteration>
                    
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

</aura:component>

el_ContactsDTInlineRowEdit:

```
<aura:component>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<!--declare aura attributes-->
<aura:attribute name="sNo" type="string" />
<aura:attribute name="contact" type="sobject" />
<aura:attribute name="accountContactRelation" type="sobject" />
<aura:attribute name='errors' type='Object' default='{!v.contact.Errors}'/>
<aura:attribute name='isIndividualAccount' type='Boolean' default='false'/>
<aura:attribute name='roleOptions' type='Object[]' default='[]'/>
<aura:attribute name='parsedRoles' type='String[]' default='[]'/>



<aura:attribute name="nameEditMode" type="boolean" default="false" access="private" />
<aura:attribute name="lastnameEditMode" type="boolean" default="false" access="private"/>
<aura:attribute name="phoneEditMode" type="boolean" default="false" access="private"/>
<aura:attribute name="mobilephoneEditMode" type="boolean" default="false" access="private"/>
<aura:attribute name="tinEditMode" type="boolean" default="false" access="private"/>
<aura:attribute name="emailEditMode" type="boolean" default="false" access="private"/>
<aura:attribute name='rolesEditMode' type='boolean' default='false' access="private"/>


<!--Table Row Start-->  
<tr class="slds-hint-parent" style='width:100%'>
    <!-- <th scope="row"><div class="slds-truncate">{!v.sNo}</div></th> -->

    <td scope="row" ondblclick="{!c.inlineEditName}" role="gridcell" aria-describedby="form-error-01"  class="{! v.errors.FirstName.hasError == true ? 'slds-cell-edit slds-has-error' : 'slds-cell-edit'}">
        <span class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread Vaterlo">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.nameEditMode == false}">
                    <span class="slds-truncate" title="First Name">{!v.contact.FirstName}</span>
                    <button onclick="{!c.inlineEditName}" class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-cell-edit__button slds-float_right" tabindex="0" title="Edit Name">
                        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:edit" size="xx-small" alternativeText="edit"/>
                    </button>
                    
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <section  tabindex="0" class="slds-popover slds-popover_edit" role="dialog" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index:2">
                            <div class="slds-popover__body slds-grow">
                                <div class="slds-form-element slds-wrap">
                                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-grow">
                                        <lightning:input 
                                            aura:id="inputId"
                                            onblur='{!c.closeEditBox}'  
                                            name="input1" 
                                            label="Last Name" 
                                            value='{!v.contact.FirstName}'
                                            style='padding:10px'
                                            />
                                        <div style='color:rgb(234, 0, 30);width:100%;white-space: pre-line;' class="slds-form-element__help" id="form-error-01">{!v.errors.FirstName.message}</div>                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <span id="form-end" tabindex="0"></span>
                        </section>  
                    </aura:set>  
                </aura:if> 
            </span>
            
    </td>
    
    <!-- the code for rest of the <td> elements was omitted to keep the component short -->
    
</tr></aura:component>
```

Comment: Try [Popovers](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/popovers/)

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I've already used popovers. Could you maybe check my code and tell me why the section element that uses the slds popover class isn't showing on top of everything else?

Comment: That is because of overflow, check overflow for container and table.